# How to calc Avg based on criteria using DAX in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I managed to get pass adding a calc col TimeToComplete based on the completion status, since DAX doesn't accept a blank, so have to put in -999.

```
[TimeToComplete] = 
if('Table1'[Status]<>"incomplete",
     'Table1'[Date completed]-'Table1'[Date Assigned],-999
  )
```

Now my issue is when I try to create a measure to get the overall Avg on the TimeToComplete column, it is taking everything including the -999 which doesn't work.   but I can't do a measure using IF.   How can I get a measure for the Overall Avg time to complete?    Also how can I get the Avg time to complete breakdown by each task. [image]

Comment: Exactly what happens if you create a measure with the definition `AVERAGE('Table1'[Date completed]-'Table1'[Date Assigned])`? What happens if you add the `IF` to this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, sorry I am not following, I tried the formula using IF and it doesn't like it as you can see from the screenshot. AvgDaysToComp = if('Table1'[Status]<>"incomplete",Average(Table1[TimeToComplete]))    Can you please elaborate a bit more how the formula for the measure should look like?  thanks

Comment: First get it working by simply using `Average(Table1[TimeToComplete]))`. If you want to exclude -999 values, they should be blank. So your original column calc should show blank instead of -999: `[TimeToComplete] = 
if('Table1'[Status]<>"incomplete",
     'Table1'[Date completed]-'Table1'[Date Assigned],BLANK()
  )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would type out a measure on the form:

```
TimeToComplete := 
AVERAGEX ( 
    FILTER ( 
        'Table1' , 
        'Table1'[Status'] <> "incomplete"
    ),
    'Table1'[TimeToComplete]
)
```

This measure should work both for the total and for each task, if you put it into a table visual for instance.

To omit the calculated column you already have added, you could do something like this, which is independent from the `'Table1'[TimeToComplete]` column:

```
TimeToComplete := 
AVERAGEX ( 
    FILTER ( 
        'Table1' , 
        'Table1'[Status'] <> "incomplete"
    ),
    DATEDIFF (
        'Table1'[Date Assigned] ,
        'Table1'[Date completed] ,
        DAY
    )
)
```

You cannot use the construct `IF ( 'Table'[Col] = "Value" ,  ... )` in a measure, only in a calculated column or within an iterator that scans a table, because then the row context supplies 1 value to compare.

Some measures can use the `SELECTEDVALUE ( ... )` function as an aggregation method to pass a specific value to compare.